# a question in Stat. aboout chi-square & standard normal

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Assume $U$~$\chi^2(5)$, $V$~$\chi^2(9)$, $Z$~$N(0,1)$, U, V, Z are mutually independent, calculate:

a. $P(Z > 0.611V^\frac{1}{2})$

b. $P(\frac{U}{V} < 1.933)$

c. Find a $c$ such that $P(\frac{U}{U+V} > c)=0.99$

d. Find a $d$ such that $P(\frac{U}{V} >d)=0.05$

- Since I written down:
- U: $f_5(u) = \frac{0.5^{2.5}}{\Gamma(2.5)}u^{1.5}e^{-0.5u}$,
  $x\geqq0$,
- V: $f_9(v) = \frac{0.5^{4.5}}{\Gamma(4.5)}v^{3.5}e^{-0.5v}$,
  $x\geqq0$,
- Z: $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Can I say $\frac{U}{V} = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{0.5^{2}}x^{-2}$ directly? 
and then calculate $\frac{\Gamma(2)}{0.5^{2}}v^{-2} = 0.99$ for example to find the c?

Comment: Look up the definitions of the F & t distributions.

Comment: Is it T=Z$\sqrt{\frac{9}{V}}$ ~ t distribution in a ; 

X=$\frac{\frac{U}{5}}{\frac{V}{9}}$ ~ F distribution in b,c,d?